# pass prop from clicked element into function as an parameter - React / D3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I am rendering a d3 map in a React app.
Given the following:

```
<path onClick={evt => this.mapClicks(evt, d)} mapData={this.getMapData(d)} />;
```

what would be the correct React way to pass `mapData` into the `mapClicks` function ?

Comment: `mapCicks(evt, this.getMapData(d))`?

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky I was originally doing this but the mapData function is a little expensive and would rather do it on initial render

Comment: is it supposed to be ran once or for every path separately

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using handler creator:

```
getPathClickHandler(data) {
  return (e) => {
    // use data here
  };
}
...
<path onClick={this.getPathClickHandler(d)} />;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getPathClickHandler(d) {
    const mapData = this.getMapData(d);
    return (e) => {
       // event, d, mapData can be used here
    };
}


<path onClick={this.handleClickForPath(d)} />;
```

But this.getMapData is still will be called on every react render, depends on the context, if it is possible to precalculate it outside of render